# Applescript empty list stops execution

Tags: calendar, applescript

I am writing an applescript to get all events from a subscribed calendar and turn them into allday events in another calendar. Below is my incomplete code thus far:

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Canvas"
        set listEvents to every event whose allday event is false
    end tell

    tell calendar "Update"

        set noMatchList to {}
        set listAllDayEvents to every event whose allday event is true
        if listAllDayEvents is null then
            set listAllDayEvent to {0}
        end if
        repeat with firstEvent in listEvents
            repeat with secondEvent in listAllDayEvents
                if firstEvent is not equal to secondEvent then
                    set end of noMatchList to firstEvent
                end if
            end repeat
    end repeat
...
```

The problem I am having is that if `listAllDayEvents` is null, i.e. there are no allday event in the Update calendar, execution stops and never makes it to the if statement. What is the problem and is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Is there an error message you're getting, or does the script just stop? If there are no allday events, listAllDayEvents should be an empty list. Not null.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I think your code logic is a little off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things.

Not sure why you are using null.

Use {} instead.  Also you missed the "s" off the end of you variable name
in:

```
 set listAllDayEvent to {0}
```

It should be:

```
set listAllDayEvents to {0}
```

**UPDATE.**

Also if I understand what you are trying to do. I think your logic in the code is a little off.

You should test for items in **listAllDayEvents** within the first repeat.

If items are found in **listAllDayEvents** then check if they match in the second repeat.

If there are no items in **listAllDayEvents** then there is no need to go into the second repeat.

Just add any items in **listEvents** to the **noMatchList** list for processing later I assume.

```
tell application "Calendar"
    tell calendar "Canvas"
        set listEvents to every event whose allday event is false
    end tell

    tell calendar "UpDate"

        set listAllDayEvents to every event whose allday event is true

    end tell

    set noMatchList to {}

    repeat with firstEvent in listEvents
        if listAllDayEvents is not {} then

            repeat with secondEvent in listAllDayEvents
                if firstEvent is not equal to secondEvent then
                    set end of noMatchList to firstEvent
                end if
            end repeat

        else

            set end of noMatchList to firstEvent
        end if

    end repeat

end tell
```

---

---

*NOTE: To any one who wants to test this code. Create two new calendars with a couple of events on each. Rather than use any of your possibly established calendars.
Calendars can be very large especially when they have some repeat events or go back years.
This means you maybe there all day waiting for the script to finish running*

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help. I have only dabbled with Applescript before, and repeat loops on lists do not make a great deal of sense to me yet. Everything seems to be working how I want it to now.

Comment: They do gat a little bit confusing when you nest them like you are.

Comment: Mark, send me a note with your email on my contact page (listed in my profile). I have a question about a script.

Comment: So it works fine the first time, but after that I get many duplicates. I have figured out that the problem is that when using 'is not equal to' the code still checks earlier items in the lists and for every item that is not equal to the one I want, it is added to the noMatch list until it gets to the matching item. I should probably rewrite it to look for matches using 'is equal to' so I only get one match instead of several.